# CCSDK Web, Enterprise IDs are not supported

Tags: javascript, adobecreativesdk

When I open up the auth window to login to the Creative Cloud Web SDK, I am presented with a message that says, 'Access Denied'.  Enterprise IDs are not supported.  Sign in with an Adobe ID to access this service.  If you do not have an Adobe ID, contact your IT administrator.  How can I set up my account so that it supports Enterprise IDs?  If I login with a personal account it works, but I need to be able to login with my enterprise account.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6uWyu.png)

Answer (score 0):

The Creative SDK doesn't support enterprise login at this time, but it is a frequently requested feature, and something we are looking into.